# Elapsed Cycles in SpaceChem

Tags: spacechem

When an assignment is completed in SpaceChem there is a summary with statistics about your solution.

What I do not understand is if it is better have high elapsed cycles or low. Because if I have 172 and 214, it tells me 214 is the best, but it seems a contradiction to me. Is it correct? Do you have an explanation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this contrived example (but the other way around)?

[image: Screenshot of SpaceChem showing elapsed cycles graph]

**Best** is your "Previous best" (and *doesn't include this run*, so you can compare).
**This** is the result of this run.

So if you're seeing This:172 and Best:214 this implies you have just managed a faster solution that your previous best, next time you will see Best:172 because **lower elapsed cycles are better**.

Comment: Good to know, that best confused me a bit

Answer (score 1):

In the graphs, the 'best' shows your previous best, together with your current score. If you then do another run with another amount of cycles, it'll show 172 as the best.